# Стоит ли заключать в кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

*«Хорошо забытое старое» опробовано в этом году в университете.*

Answer (score 2):

**«Хорошо забытое старое» опробовано в этом году в университете.**

Выражение всем известное, и оно обычно включается в речь без кавычек, но в данном случае используется только его часть, поэтому кавычки лучше поставить.

Примеры

А вообще **все новое** ― это, как известно, **хорошо забытое старое**.

Мама мотивировала свои требования тем, что в**се новое — это хорошо забытое старое** и что в моде снова миди и даже макси.

И так как «**все новое ― это хорошо забытое старое**», мы предлагаем вам ознакомиться с тем, какой «словарь» болезней предлагает китайская традиционная медицина.